# get filename in the batch file each time a new file is placed

Tags: batch-file

My requirement is - i need to read the filename from an input folder say - `C:\Encrypt\In` and pass it to the command java.exe -jar D:\SYS\src\PI\IN\Cryptage.jar -rc4 -crypt D:\SYS\src\PI\IN\Decrypt\ D:\src\PI\IN\Encrypt\ %VAR1%%VAR2%

i tried doing the one below - but no luck

```
set VAR1=FOR /R C:\Encrypt\In %F in (*.*) do echo %~nF
set VAR2=ABCD

echo %VAR1%%VAR2% (concatenate the filename with "ABCD" as constant)


java.exe -jar D:\SYS\src\PI\IN\Cryptage.jar -rc4 -crypt D:\SYS\src\PI\IN\Decrypt\ D:\src\PI\IN\Encrypt\ %VAR1%%VAR2%
```

(pass it here - so that each time a file comes in the input directory the variables can pick up the file names dynamically through the variables)

echo `%VAR1%%VAR2%` is not working.

Comment: First and foremost, don't put spaces around `=` in `set` commands; you'll break absolutely everything. Secondly, you can't use a set statement to store the output of a command in a variable; you have to use that command as the command in a `for /F` loop and store the output to whatever variable the loop uses. Finally, I recommend searching for an answer to the problem of actively monitoring a folder for changes. SO gets multiple questions about that on a regular basis. (I'm pretty sure I saw two yesterday!)

Comment: thank you for the inputs - but i am new to batch file - i need the code. and i need to pass the filename to the command line - how can i do that? - actively monitoring a folder for changes - well yes i saw them too - how do i include them in the command line where i am calling the executable jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a commented batch code for your task:

```
@echo off
set "ScanFolder=C:\Encrypt\In"

rem The loop runs command DIR to get a list of files with archive attribute set.
rem Directories are ignored even if archive attribute is set on a directory.
rem On each file with archive attribute currently set the archive attribute
rem is removed from file and then the command is started to process the file.
rem After all files with archive attribute were processed, the batch file
rem waits 5 seconds before scanning the folder again. The loop is infinite
rem and can be breaked only by pressing Ctrl+C or closing command prompt
rem window to stop command line interpreter.

:Loop
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /AA-D /B "%ScanFolder%" 2^>nul') do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -A "%ScanFolder%\%%~nxF"
    java.exe -jar D:\SYS\src\PI\IN\Cryptage.jar -rc4 -crypt D:\SYS\src\PI\IN\Decrypt\ D:\src\PI\IN\Encrypt\ "%ScanFolder%\%%~nxF"
)
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n 6 127.0.0.1>nul
goto Loop
```

`java.exe` should be called with full path enclosed in double quotes if possible as in this case command line interpreter would not always need to search for it in the folders of environment variable **PATH**.

Note: The batch file calls the new file with full path, file name and extension without anything appended. Of course you can replace `%%~nxF` at end of line calling `java.exe` also with `%%~nFABCD` if this is necessary in your environment.

For an explanation of the used commands and how they work in detail open a command prompt window and execute following commands to see the help of those commands:

- `attrib /?`
- `dir /?`
- `for /?`
- `ping /?`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anyway - i achieved it through this :- cd C:\Encrypt\In\ for %%f in (.) do ( rem echo %%~nfAPSI set v=%%~nfAPSI ) echo %v%